# lambda expression is called in the while(),Why do we need to add () after the lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++11

```
while ([&s]()->bool {
  cout << "Please Input you word<input \"q \" to exit>:"; 
  return (cin >> s) && (s != "[enter image description here][1]q"); 
}())
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambda expressions are function definitions. When you call a function, you must use parentheses, but when you pass functions around as arguments, you use only the name. If we store the lambda function in a variable called "condition", you may be able to see this better:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    

using namespace std;    

int main() {
  string s{};
  auto condition = [&s]() -> bool {
    cout << "Please Input you word:";
    return ((cin >> s) && (s != "enter image description here"));
  };
  while (condition()) {
  }
  return (0);
}
```

Example: http://cpp.sh/3k6js

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

This could also be written as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>       

int main() {
  std::string s{};
  while ([&s] {
    std::cout << "Please Input you word:";
    return ((std::cin >> s) && (s != "enter image description here"));
  }()) {
  }
  return (0);
}
```

Example: http://cpp.sh/7v7gd

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: IIRC,lamba's return type can be deduced by compiler